# Is pyJoules library suitable for ARM device?

Tags: python, arm

I'm not very familiar to these kind of considerations so I hope I don't say something very wrong.

I'm willing to check the power consumption of a Python application I developped on an embedded device. It's running on an ARM microprocessor. I found a tool that seems perfect : pyJoules library. However the documentation mention Intel CPU, which for what I know is different from ARM CPU. So I was wondering if the library was compatible with my need, thus with ARM CPU.

Does somebody know ? If it's not, is there maybe another tool easy to use you could recommand me ?

Thank you !

Comment: In some ways the library is only part of the story.  For instance, if you send to swap, you might be using disk/SSD and this consumes power.  The pyJoule is only using the CPU power.  There can be other things that dwarf CPU consumption, like a LCD backlight on an ARM CPU.  For an Intel CPU, it is like a toaster and it will dominate power consumption.  [Cycle count as power measure](https://ejers.org/index.php/ejers/article/download/184/68/&usg=AOvVaw0HYGpXvv4picinwgoYZxIT) is a paper on trying to estimate this.  That said for a custom embedded platform, there is often a PMIC to measure power.